# Pardot dynamic From address

Tags: salesforce, pardot

I need to move emails that are being sent through Apex over to Pardot. Currently the emails are being sent from Apex because they want to dynamically set a From address. They do this by accessing the Org-Wide Email Address: for instance, they have a two contacts- one (contact x) who is associated with an Org called "foo" and another (contact y) associated with an Org called "bar". They want to send an email from noreply@foo.com to contact X and an email from noreply@bar to contact Y. Does Pardot have this kind of functionality

Answer (score 0):

Pardot doesn't have this type of functionality out of the box (to dynamically assign the sender based on conditional logic).  However, based on assigned user you could segment by sender (if you had two record owners "noreply@foo and noreply@bar").

The other alternative I could think of is an Engagement Studio campaign with rules segmenting by org; each org-associated contact would then receive a different email template sent from a different general user ("noreply@foo or noreply@bar").